# Karmic Koala (Ubuntu): enable remote x clients through TCP

Tags: linux, tcp, ubuntu-9.10, x11

It seems every version of Ubuntu has a different way to enable remote connections to the local X server.

I'm asking this question, while I do my own research: how can I enable the X server listening to TCP port 6000 on my machine, thus allowing remote X clients to connect to said port and use my display?

Comment: I recommend using socat, as explained here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1360248/364151. The solution is not specific to a particular window manager or Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on information found in [this page about enabling XDCMP](http://www.peppertop.com/blog/?p=690) and the file /etc/gdm/gdm.schemas, I managed to create the following file:

```
# /etc/gdm/custom.conf
[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[security]
DisallowTCP=false

[debug]
```

I also changed the /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc file to:

```
exec /usr/bin/X11/X
```

i.e. I removed the `-nolisten tcp` options to the X executable. I don't know if I needed to. You might want to try avoiding this edit.

After that, all that is needed is a restart of the gdm process:

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

You can verify the success as:

```
tzot@tzot-laptop:/etc/X11
$ netstat -an | grep -F 6000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::6000                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: You're right, "every version of Ubuntu has a different way": your answer doesn't work anymore in Linux Mint 19 (Ubuntu 18 I think). It's partly Xorg's fault ([see this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=785495#10)), now `-nolisten tcp` is implied, you need an explicit `-listen tcp`! I found no way to have `gdm3` add this argument when it runs `Xorg`. It's easy with `sddm` (`man sddm.conf`).

Answer (score 3):

if found it in 
/etc/gdm/gdm.schemas

converted true to false, now it works

```
<schema>
  <key>security/DisallowTCP</key>
  <signature>b</signature>
  <default>false</default>
</schema>
```

http://supermanhelp.com

Comment: I tried this and and the other /etc/gdm/custom.conf tweak, restarted gdm. ps shows X is no longer running with -nolisten tcp ... and yet tcp X connections are still denied even after using xhost + . I'm running Ubuntu 10.10. (Like others, I have a couple use cases where ssh X forwarding is insufficient such using Emacs to open frames on multiple displays). 

Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1):

In later versions of ubuntu the procedure above no longer works due to a new display manager LightDM.  To check this execute the shell command:

```
    ps aux | grep `cat /tmp/.X0-lock'
```

and check for lightdm and the notcp switch.  If found update your system by adding to /etc/lightdm.conf the following entry in the [SeatDefaults] section:

```
    xserver-allow-tcp=true
```

Finally restart your computer and check it works with

```
   netstat -an | grep -F 6000
```

as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

As every configuration is different, I found mine with:

```
sudo grep --include=\*.conf -rwl '/etc/' -e "SeatDefaults"
```

If you don't find a file, you can try expanding the search by changing `'/etc/'` to `'/'`

Once you locate your file add what others suggested under the `[SeatDefaults]` section:

```
xserver-allow-tcp=true
```

Save the file and restart the computer. 
You may need to use the `xauth` on the server you want to access (full info [here](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xauth.1.xhtml)), e.x.:

```
xauth extract − $DISPLAY | ssh TheRemoteHost xauth merge −
```

You may also need to use `xhost` ([here](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xhost.1.xhtml)).
Finally in a new console <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> use:

```
sudo X -query TheXhost :1
```