# RHEL6: allow remote X clients

Tags: vnc, rhel6

Two hosts, both running RHEL6.2.  One (hostA) has a X installed, the other (hostB) does not.  Installing X on the second host is not an option.  Runnning 'echo $DISPLAY' on hostA returns ':10.0'.

On hostA, I've:
- xhost +

On hostB, I've:
- export DISPLAY=hostA:10.0

Running 'ps -ef | grep nolisten' on hostA shows:
me 2400  2398  3 10:47 ?        00:00:01 Xvnc :10 -geometry 1680x1050 -depth 24 -rfbauth /home/me/.vnc/sesman_me_passwd -bs -ac -nolisten tcp -localhost -dpi 96

How do I remove the '-nolisten tcp -localhost' remove Xvnc?

I've followed the points in [Karmic Koala (Ubuntu): enable remote x clients through TCP](https://serverfault.com/questions/99147/karmic-koala-ubuntu-enable-remote-x-clients-through-tcp) without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to hostA from hostB using ssh with X11 forwarding enabled. `ssh -Y username@hostA` or `ssh -X username@hostA` should work. From your session, run the X application of your choice.

Comment: Thanks @ewwhite but it turned out to be hard set in /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you wish to have a program running on hostB to display its the UI on hostA, which apparently is running Xvnc (which again means you'd be seeing the actual UI on a vnc client possibly running elsewhere).

You could use ssh X11 forwarding on the lines of what [ewwhite](https://serverfault.com/users/13325/ewwhite) had [pointed out](https://serverfault.com/a/362071/111296). However you'd have to connect from hostA (which runs X) to host B (which runs the app that needs X). That is to say, run the command `ssh -Y user@hostB` on hostA, and in the newly connected ssh session run the application program.

Also, I don't think you'd have to enable TCP listening if you use ssh X11 forwarding. ssh daemon on hostB would use the unix socket to talk to X running locally.